# Ruby Reads Different File Sizes for Line Reads

Tags: ruby, file-read

I need to do something where the file sizes are crucial. This is producing strange results

```
filename = "testThis.txt"
total_chars = 0
file = File.new(filename, "r")
file_for_writing = nil
while (line = file.gets)
  total_chars += line.length
end
puts "original size #{File.size(filename)}"
puts "Totals #{total_chars}"
```

like this

```
original size 20121
Totals 20061
```

Why is the second one coming up short?

Edit: Answerers' hunches are right: the test file has 60 lines in it. If I change this line

```
  total_chars += line.length + 1
```

it works perfectly. But on *nix this change would be wrong?

**Edit:** Follow up is now [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628096). Thanks!

Comment: Correct, that fix would only work on windoze.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are special characters stored in the file that delineate the lines:

- CR LF (0x0D 0x0A) (\r\n) on Windows/DOS and
- 0x0A (\n) on UNIX systems.

Ruby's `gets` uses the UNIX method.  So, if you read a Windows file you would lose 1 byte for every line you read as the \r\n bytes are converted to \n.

Also `String.length` is not a good measure of the size of the string (in bytes).  If the String is not ASCII, one character may be represented by more than one byte (Unicode).  That is, it returns the number of characters in the String, not the number of bytes.

To get the size of a file, use `File.size(file_name)`.

Comment: Actually, depending on the version of Ruby you're using, str.length might return the number of bytes or the number of characters. (I believe in 1.8.6 and up, it gives you number of characters. Before that, number of bytes.) One more thing to keep in mind if you plan on this being portable.

Comment: This is great. Would you mind having a look at the followup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628096

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that you are on Windows, and your "testThis.txt" file has \r\n line endings.  When the file is opened in text mode, each line ending will be converted to a single \n character.  Therefore you'll lose 1 character per line.

Does your test file have 60 lines in it?  That would be consistent with this explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The line-ending issues is the most likely culprit here.

It's also worth noting that if the character encoding of the text file is something other than ASCII, you will have a discrepancy between the 2 as well. If the file is UTF-8, this will work for english and some european languages that use just standard ASCII alphabet symbols. Beyond that, the file size and character counts can vary wildly (up to 4 or even 6 times the file size compared to the character count).

Relying on '1 character = 1 byte' is just asking for trouble as it is almost certainly going to fail at some point.

Comment: Now the real question: what is better than 1 character = 1 byte?

Comment: 1 character = 1 character, 1 byte = 1 byte and never the twain should meet :)

Comment: Terse, but I get the idea. I'll comment back if I can't make sense of it. Thanks!

Comment: Now I've gotten to part 2. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628096/ruby-length-of-a-line-of-a-file-in-bytes